# Faulty response from the Java Script function implemented in JSP

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to implement a java Script function to validate 2 inputs that are inputted through a form.

The function needs to check whether the inputted password (psw) is similar to the inputted repeat password(psw-repeat).

I have been unsuccessful so far. Even if i enter 2 dissimilar inputs the function returns true.
What can be the fault in my function?

userregistration.jsp

```js
function matchpass() {

  var firstpassword = document.myform.psw.value;
  var secondpassword = document.myform.psw - repeat.value;

  if (firstpassword == secondpassword) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("password must be same!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" action="RegisterControllerServlet" method="post">

  <br><br>
  <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

  <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>
  <hr>


  <button type="submit" class="registerbtn" onSubmit="return matchpass();">Register</button>
  </div>
```

I want to be able to validate the 2 passwords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `return` and change `onSubmit` to `onclick`

```
<button type="submit" class="registerbtn" onclick="matchpass()">Register</button>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean they get registered? Are you saying that the `matchpass` function runs but the result is always returning true?

Comment: yes this is a form to register the user so after filling all the details but even after typing 2 different passwords after i click the register button the entered details are submitted

Comment: I think your other problem is in this line var `secondpassword = document.myform.psw - repeat.value;` should be `secondpassword = document.myform.psw-repeat.value;`

Comment: what do you mean is it because there is some kind of space

Comment: yes, I believe so.  You can also try adding `console.log(firstpassword, secondpassword)` into the function to help you visualize the difference. But I believe removing the spaces will fix your problem.

Comment: but there are no spaces in my code, can it be because of the action to the servlet----------usinf the name as psw-repeat is fine right?

Comment: try replacing the `-` with an underscore `_` if this doesn't work you should try to `console.log` the values for your passwords.

Comment: Great I would appreciate it if you accept my answer.

Comment: But now there is a problem the javascript part works but still the user is registered. Even though the error is shown after i click okay on the error the user is registered, i want to stop it

Comment: Could make another post and I will take a look.

Comment: I am sorry i dont get you

Comment: Could you create a new Stack Overflow Question for this new issue and I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function matchpass() {
  
  var firstpassword = document.myform.psw.value;
  var secondpassword = document.myform.psw_repeat.value;

  if (firstpassword == secondpassword) {
    document.myform.submit();
  } else {
    alert("password must be same!");    
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" action="RegisterControllerServlet" method="post">

  <br><br>
  <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

  <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw_repeat" required>
  <hr>
</form>
 
 <button class="registerbtn" onclick="matchpass();">Register</button>
```

Comment: @GeorgeSilva im just wondering how you tried. Run the code snippet and check

Comment: if i run the code snippet it works but inside my code it doesnt

Comment: @GeorgeSilva because you have to rename `psw-repeat` to `psw_repeat`, because js reads it like this `document.myform.psw - repeat.value ` as 2 seperate element and object. And learn to read `errors` in console